# rxJs scan - doesn't emit if observable is empty

Tags: rxjs

I have a bit of code that looks like this:

```js
function getEvensSquared(array) {
  return rxjs.of(array).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.flatMap(array => {
      return rxjs.from(
        array.filter(n => n % 2 === 0)
      );
    }),
    rxjs.operators.switchMap(n => {
      return rxjs.of(n * n);
    }),
    rxjs.operators.scan((acc, cur) => {
      acc.push(cur);
      return acc;
    }, [])
  );
}

getEvensSquared([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe(v => {
  console.log("1,2,3,4");
  console.log(v)
});

getEvensSquared([1, 3, 5]).subscribe(v => {
  console.log("1,3,5"); //never prints
  console.log(v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Essentially it is:

1. Get a stream of arrays of `ObjectA`.
2. Convert the array in to a stream of filtered `ObjectA`.
3. Convert the stream of `ObjectA` into a stream of `ObjectB`.
4. Accumulate the stream of `ObjectB` into a stream of arrays of `ObjectB`.

The problem is - if there are no approved bookings, the `flatMap` operator never emits. Is there a way to default in this case?

I tried putting `defaultIfEmpty([])` after the scan - but that didn't work.

Comment: how about trying to put defaultIfEmpty after the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Positing this as an answer - because it works for the example I've given - `defaultIfEmpty` does work in this scenario.

```js
function getEvensSquared(array) {
  return rxjs.of(array).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.flatMap(array => {
      return rxjs.from(
        array.filter(n => n % 2 === 0)
      );
    }),
    rxjs.operators.switchMap(n => {
      return rxjs.of(n * n);
    }),
    rxjs.operators.scan((acc, cur) => {
      acc.push(cur);
      return acc;
    }, []), 
    rxjs.operators.defaultIfEmpty([])

  );
}

getEvensSquared([1, 2, 3, 4]).subscribe(v => {
  console.log("1,2,3,4");
  console.log(v)
});

getEvensSquared([1, 3, 5]).subscribe(v => {
  console.log("1,3,5"); //works
  console.log(v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.2.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```